# Live streaming in flutter app with hls support

Tags: flutter, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I am developing a live streaming app where i need to live stream hls supported videos. I tried to use chewie controller but i am getting some errors.

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
final videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
  Uri.parse(widget.url),
);

videoPlayerController.initialize().then((value) {
  
});

chewieController = ChewieController(
    videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
    autoPlay: true,
    looping: false,
    fullScreenByDefault: true,
    draggableProgressBar: false,
    showControlsOnInitialize: false,
    isLive: true,
    autoInitialize: true,
  );
 }
```

this is my initstate and this is where i use it inside widget tree:

```
Chewie(
        controller: chewieController!,
      ),
```

These are the errors that i am getting:

> I/ExoPlayerImpl( 5228): Init c85e96a [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.7] [curtana, Redmi Note 9 Pro, Xiaomi, 30]
> I/ExoPlayerImpl( 5228): Init 1f8e009 [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.7] [curtana, Redmi Note 9 Pro, Xiaomi, 30]
> I/ExoPlayerImpl( 5228): Init 949aa27 [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.7] [curtana, Redmi Note 9 Pro, Xiaomi, 30]
> E/flutter ( 5228): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Future already completed

also these:

> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 17 lines
> 2
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 17 lines
> 2
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 17 lines
> 2
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 16 lines
> 2
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 17 lines
> 2
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 17 lines
> 2
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 17 lines
> 2
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 16 lines
> 2
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 17 lines
> 2
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 16 lines
> 2
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 17 lines
> 2
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 17 lines
> 2
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 16 lines
> 2
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 17 lines
> 2
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> I/chatty  ( 5228): uid=10322(com.example.progresscenter_app_v4) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 10 lines
> 175
> W/DefaultLoadControl( 5228): Target buffer size reached with less than 500ms of buffered media data.
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5228): Playback error
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5228):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Unexpected runtime error
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5228):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:628)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5228):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5228):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5228):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5228):   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Playback stuck buffering and not loading
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5228):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1088)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5228):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:502)
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 5228):       ... 3 more

Comment: video_player worked well for me playing .m3u8 files. So how do you upload video from camera to server?

Comment: Videos are already uploaded from console side. Issue is flutter is not able to load or play more than 10 video players at same time.